# Syntax in $or statement

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-compass

[image]

I have the following filter which I am trying to test in MongoDB Compass:

```
{$or: ["OwedTaxes": {$regex: "$"},"OwedTaxes": {$exists: false}]}
```

Meaning the `OwedTaxes` field contains a "$" sign or does not exist.

There is a syntax error but I don't understand what it is. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need an additional pair of brackets around each of the entries in the $or array. Eg $or: [ {...}, {...} ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap each element in the array with `{ }` curly brace to represent a valid BSON document.

```
{
  $or: [
    { "OwedTaxes": {$regex: "$"} },
    { "OwedTaxes": {$exists: false} }
  ]
}
```